# Теряются HTML-теги при выводе в консоли

Tags: java

Имеется код

```
textWithLinks = textWithLinks.replaceAll(name, "<a href=\""+name+".html\">"+name+"</a>");
System.out.println(textWithLinks);
```

Как должен работать:

```
<a href="файл.html">файл</a>
```

Как на самом деле:

```
файл.html файл
```

Короче говоря, вывод сожрал теги, как исправить?

Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо заранее

Comment: А вы покажите что у вас в `name` и что в `textWithLinks` .... скорее всего просто не находит он name ваш

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нее, с теми в все нормальо просто не отображаись теги

Comment: Если ТАМ все нормально, а только проблемы в тегах, то как объясните нормальное поведение? https://ideone.com/HPTU50

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  вы идею используете?

Comment: Да. проблем нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский понял прост впервые вижу этот сайт вероятно очередной баг нетбинса

Comment: в `replaceAll` первый аргумент - регулярное выражение. Скорее всего вам нужен просто `replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы не сказал бы, что проблема в html-тегах, да и консоль нормально выводит подобную строку, не знаю, но причина вероятно в `<` и `>`, которые являются спецсимволами и с ними скорее всего проблема отображения, я не скажу причину, однако я бы все же хотел бы узнать ее, поэтому все же попытайся заменить эти символы в данном методе эквивалентами

`<` - `&lt;`

`>` - `&gt;`

Т.е в итоге у тебя должно получиться:

```
.replaceAll(name, "&lt;a href=\""+name+".html\"&gt;"+name+"&lt;/a&gt;");
```

**UPD:** А вообще, наиболее вероятная причина, это использования методов извлечения текста из html-кода, так как подобных проблем на практике я не встречал.

Comment: Не. без спец символов все нормально должно быть

Comment: спасибо огромное!) действительно работает однако я нашел другие проблемы в коде